# C++ mt19937 always giving same number, even when seeding

Tags: c++, random, containers

I am currently having an issue where my RNG is always giving me the same number - even when I am (supposedly) seeding the value every time.

the code in the class is:

```
    int RandomNumberGenerator()
{
    std::mt19937 engine;
    auto seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    engine.seed((unsigned long)seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 100);

    return distribution(engine);
}
```

And the code calling it is:

```
vector<int> iv;
    generate_n(back_inserter(iv), 5, RandomNumberGenerator);
    cout << "\nVector content: ";
    copy(iv.begin(), iv.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

Surely each time the generate_n function

Comment: I can not reproduce that issue. Are you sure, you have successfully recompiled after you have added the seed?

Comment: Well, that is pretty random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you create `n` different engines and you seed them with the clock value. Chances are that the clock didn't move in the time `generate_n()` ran and all the engines where seeded with the same value.

You should seed a generator once and use it multiple times.

Example adapted from [uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 100);

    std::vector<int> vi;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vi), 5, std::bind(dis, gen));


    std::copy(begin(vi), end(vi), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

You can see it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b8133e9bdb2a7647)

*Note*

[Some people may say that your code was indeed returning random numbers](https://xkcd.com/221/) :)

Comment: Here's the way I recommend seeding in the standard library: `std::random_device r; std::seed_seq seed{r(),r(),r(),r(),r(),r(),r(),r()}; std::mt19937 eng(seed);` This ensures a practically unlimited number of starting states, instead of just 4 billion, which is small enough to sometimes be a problem. I was motivated to make this my default recommendation by [M.E. O'Neill](http://www.pcg-random.org/blog/), (although I had used it before myself). If you're willing to go beyond the standard library that link provides some alternatives that offer some advantages.

Comment: @bames53 Really interesting, I bookmarked the link, thank you very much.